# asp:button and javascript popup

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, button, popup

I want to add a simple confirm, are you sure dialog when you click an asp:button which does postback.
Something like:

```
OnClientClick="if(confirm('Format the hard disk?'))
alert('something');
else alert('something else')"
```

Problem is that whether you click ok or cancel it still posts back.
How to make it so that it only posts back on OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to do a postback based on the selection from the confirmation dialog, this might be simpler:

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what is needed. Simple and to the point :)

Answer (score 1):

In short "`....; return false;`" stops the click, example below not using inline JS:

**Markup:**

```
OnClientClick="confirmSomething()";
```

**JS Function:**

```
function confirmSomething()
{
    var result = confirm('Format the hard disk?');
    if(result == 1)
    {
       alert('something');
       return true; //continue click event
    }
    else if(result == 0)
    {
       alert('something else');
       return false; //stop click event
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use next:

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete this entity?');"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use return false.

```
OnClientClick="if(confirm('Format the hard disk?')) alert('something'); else {alert('something else'); return false;}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the confirm instead.

see: http://rumandcode.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/javascript-confirm-on-aspnet-button/